# Magento - change Sort order to Name in Search Result

Tags: magento

how can change Sort order to Name in Magento Search Result page?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't you have a toolbar where sorting method is selected?

Comment: I have masked it, my chef don't want to show it. Any solution to make a default sort order by product name ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `&order=name` to your query string. In order to do it go to `/app/design/frontend/{your-interface}/{your-theme}/template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml` and add

```
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="name"/>
```

just before closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life ! 
I have only added it to form.mini.phtml

Comment: Do you know also how can I order the suggestions in the Autocomplete search form ??

Comment: This will be much more complicated. I suggest making another question for it.

Comment: Alex's answer is more appropriate. I have seen issues where simply using a query string to set sorting features breaks other sort features.

Answer (score 21):

In your theme (for example `/app/design/frontend/{your-interface}/{your-theme}/layout/`) create a file `local.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
            <action method="setSortBy"><param>name</param></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
            <action method="setSortBy"><param>name</param></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
</layout>
```

Comment: On Magento `1.7.0.2` I had to place this file in `/app/design/frontend/default/{theme}/layout/local.xml`. Other than that, worked perfectly.

Comment: +1 for this method, as simply adding in query strings to set the sort is questionable.

Comment: Cool! Now, what if you want to sort by two columns? i.e. resulting in a MySQL clause "ORDER BY `name` ASC, `popularity` DESC` for example? Can that be done with XML settings?

Comment: Not sure. I doubt it is possible without customization. I suggest you open a new question for that.