# Magento reset sort order on new search

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Magento "remembers" the sort by order selected by the user. Although the default might be relevance, the user could change it to name or price for example either while browsing a search results page or even in a category list page. This could become a problem if the user does another search later and does not notice or remember that the default sort order has been changed from relevance to something else, making the search results seem pretty poor if the user was not expecting a list sorted by anything other than relevance.

How do I make a new search reset the sort order back to relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304154/magento-change-sort-order-to-name-in-search-result), modify `app/design/frontend/{yourname}/{yourtheme}/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`

and add two hidden fields in the form tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dir" value="desc" />
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="relevance" />
```

So whenever a new search is performed from the quick search, it will by default sort by descending relevance.